# How to create a constructor for a struct in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have recently started to do object-oriented stuff in Julia and have enjoyed using structs (the Python equivalent to a class?).

I read the documentation about structs [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#struct), but I did not see anything about constructors or methods in the struct. I have seen structs used a few places where someone actually defines a function inside of the struct. How can I do that and why would you want to do that?

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you finish reading carefully the documentation suggested by StefanKarpinski (and it is really good), have a look for the *[Parameters](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl)* package which, in my opinion, makes the object-oriented transformation to Julia much nicer.

Have a look at this code:

```
@with_kw mutable struct Agent
    age = 0
    income = rand()
end

function Agent(age::Int)
    income = rand()+age*10
    Agent(age, income)
end
```

And now some usages:

```
julia> Agent()
Agent
  age: Int64 0
  income: Float64 0.28109332504865625


julia> Agent(income=33)
Agent
  age: Int64 0
  income: Int64 33


julia> Agent(age=3)
Agent
  age: Int64 3
  income: Float64 0.5707873066917069


julia> Agent(30)
Agent
  age: Int64 30
  income: Float64 300.1706559468855
```

The last constructor was the custom-made one, while the three previous were automatically generated by the `@withkw` macro.

Last, but not least. Consider a loop reference data structure, i.e., where AgentY1 can only have friends of type AgentY2 and AgentY2 can only have friends of type AgentY1:

To my best knowledge (maybe someone can correct me if I am wrong) this can be only achieved using the macro:

```
@with_kw mutable struct AgentY1
    age::Int
    friends=AgentY2[]
end


@with_kw mutable struct AgentY2
    age::Int
    friends=AgentY1[]
end
```

And now sample usage:

```
julia> aa = AgentY1(age=11)
AgentY1
  age: Int64 11
  friends: Array{AgentY2}((0,))
```

This is how I do my OO programming in Julia.

Comment: Note, that this does not prevent you from creating objects that have other friends like `julia> AgentY1( age = 1, friends=AgentY1[] )
AgentY1
  age: Int64 1
  friends: Array{AgentY1}((0,))` you'd need inner constructors or specify `friends` as `friends::Vector{AgentY2}` for that.

Comment: This is good point and in particular you can have situation such as `typeof(aa) == typeof(bb) == AgentY1` evaluates to `true` and `typeof(aa.friends) == typeof(bb.friends)` evaluates to `false`. I am actually wondering if this is some kind of loophole in the typing system or a desired behavior? Nevertheless, there is no other way to define loops in `struct` data structures in Julia and such loops are very standard in problems such as agent based simulations (sometimes I am just using object ids which then is not quite elegant)

Comment: Should be possible with the incomplete initialization now (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#Incomplete-Initialization-1). Haven't tested it though.